# CSS transform blurry on safari when content overflows

Tags: css, safari, css-transforms

Pen: https://codepen.io/mustafa0x/pen/bGWqjjj

```html
<div class=outer>
  <div class=inner>line 1<br>
line 2<br>
line 3<br>
line 4<br>
line 5<br>
line 6<br>
line 7<br>
line 8<br>
line 9<br>
line 10<br>
line 11<br>
line 12<br>
line 13<br>
line 14<br>
line 15<br>
line 16<br>
line 17<br>
line 18<br>
line 19<br>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.outer {
  transform: scale(2.5) translate(50%, 50%);
}
.inner {
  height: 290px;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

[image: css-transform-blurry-safari]

Comment: It's not fuzzy on Safari IOS 14 (iPad) - what system are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth Safari 14.1.1 on macOS and iOS, Safari TP on macOS.